# Can you use raw body for GET request in axios?

Tags: reactjs, get

I am trying to call a GET request with body params using axios... My server side code is saying that the request is coming back as null. So I am left wondering is this even possible? I have taken code from a bunch of different sources to come up with the below. Thanks

```
import axios from 'axios'

var data = JSON.stringify({
    "QueryStart": "2012-02-02 09:31:52.860176",
    "QueryEnd": "2022-02-02 09:31:52.860176"
  });

// Create instance called instance
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:44373/PropertyDashboard/RollupNumbers',
    headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9jasdjsfkjfhdsfjksfjffkjkfdhsfjdsfhk', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data : data
});

export default {
    getData: () =>
    instance({
        'method':'GET',
        'headers': {
            'content-type':'application/json'  // override instance defaults
        },
        //'url':'/api',
         'data': {
             'item1':'data1',
             'item2':'item2',
         },
    }),
    postData: () =>
    instance({
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'content-type':'application/json'  // override instance defaults
        },
        //'url':'/api',
         'data': {
             'item1':'data1',
             'item2':'item2',
         },
          
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer but surprisingly not a word in google